# Using s3a on linux machine fail for >100 columns parquet

Tags: linux, scala, parquet, spark-shell, amazon-s3-access-points

I am using s3a to read from database into dataframe and write to .parquet(s3a://bucketname//folder).
It works for <100 column dataframe but crashes.exits spark-shell for >~100 columns. cannot find any material if this is column limitation/version issue/memory issue?
Hoping to find some direction from experienced community.

PS. Same code as below works on Eclipse Windows on my local machine, but issue on linux instance

spark version- 2.4.0-cdh6.3.3
scala version- 2.11.12
Java version- 1.8

```
def execute(sql:String) = {//defined connection }
val df_sql = ("select * from sampletable")
val df_exe = execute(df_sql)
df_exe.write.parquet(s3a://bucketname/folder)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer, in case someone reaches this question.
when calling spark-submit, increase the driver-memory to fit 1 partition of the file being written. I used 16g